# NodeJS Async connection to Mongo DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to write a async function in nodejs that I will use to display data in my front-end.  Can anyone point out my error.  It is probably fairly obvious.

```
    export function getData() {

      const client = new MongoClient(url);
      var query = {"pos_date" : "2019-07-18"};
      console.log('get mongo data');

      return new client.connect((url).dbo.dbo.collection("positions_eod").find(query).toArray())
      .then(function(data){
        return data;
      })
    }
```

Comment: could you secify what "your error" is?

Comment: You are calling `client.connect()` and you are passing it `(url).dbo.dbo.collection("positions_eod").find(query).toArray()`. Doesn't look like a valid syntax, doesn't make much sense

Comment: Also why not use Mongoose?